# Repeating pattern of 3D objects (a fence)

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have a 3D model of a fence. The model contains 1 start post and one end post with a connecting glass pane in between. Consider I want to be able to specify an arbitrary length of fence that I want to place in a virtual world. How would I go about manipulating the original 3D model in order to change it to this length along with additional fence posts, if that is even possible?

For example: Say I want to place a fence with 4 posts with total length L, where the height of the fence is the same as the original model but the width of the connecting pane could change depending on the length L.

```
|-|-|-|
```

As I see now there is only a few possible ways to go about it:

1) Manipulating the original object, by making some kind of custom geometry. I really have no idea where to even start here, except that I need to extend or inherit the [SCNGeometry property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometry) and then changing the vertices of the geometry in some meaningful way.

2) Scaling the width of the posts and panes in the original model according to the number of posts wanted and relative to the total length L (thereby keeping the correct dimensions of the posts), then placing multiple instances of the fence along side each other where the posts overlap. 
This would probably not be ideal due to rendering issues that could occur but it might be the only way.

Any other suggestions or tips on what I should be looking for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a testing code (macOS version) that you can use as a starting point. Try it to see how for-in loop works. Also, you need implement a method to calculate the distance for your fence (here's a `distance` value).

```
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: NSViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SCNScene()
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
        scnView.scene = scene
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        scnView.backgroundColor = NSColor.black

      
        // A PLANE FOR CHECKING A SIZE OF 3D STRUCTURE
        let plane = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: 15, height: 1))
        plane.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("UVmap.jpg"))
        plane.position = SCNVector3(7.5, -1.5, 0.5)
        plane.rotation = SCNVector4(1, 0, 0, -CGFloat.pi/2)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(plane)

        
        // ALL YOU NEED TO DO HERE – IS TO CHANGE THIS VALUE
        let distance: CGFloat = 12.7     // comes from tape-measure tool

        let nth_part: CGFloat = (distance - CGFloat(Int(distance))) / CGFloat(Int(distance))
        var section: CGFloat = 0
                              
        print(distance)                  // floating point distance
        print(Int(distance))             // rounded to lower integer
        print(nth_part)                  // 0.7 / 12 = 0.058
        
        for _ in 1...Int(distance) {     // loop for building 12 sections
            
            let postNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.11, height: 3, length: 0.11, chamferRadius: 0))
            postNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(postNode)
            
            // width of each pane is 1m + 0.058m
            let paneNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: (1 + nth_part), height: 2.9, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0))
            paneNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.blue
            
            // offset for next pane -– 0.558m, 1.116m, 2.174m, etc
            paneNode.position = SCNVector3(((section + 0.5) + (nth_part * section)), 0, 0)
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(paneNode)
            
            // offset for next post -– 1.058m, 2.116m, 3.174m, etc
            let lastPostostNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.11, height: 3, length: 0.11, chamferRadius: 0))
            lastPostostNode.position = SCNVector3(((section + 1) + (nth_part * section)), 0, 0)
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lastPostostNode)
            
            section += 1
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.** In iOS project use `UIViewController`, `UIImage` and `UIColor`.

[image]

And here's a texture for a plane to check if distance is true or not:

[image]

## Measure Tool implementing...

> If you'd like to know how to implement a **`measure tool`** [go here](https://github.com/whitesmith/MeasureThings).

Comment: Great idea but I’m a little bit unsure if this could help me when the distance is not an integer. Would it be possible to change the increment to the counter (and the position offset) somehow to account for this? To be clear the width of the panes would be allowed to change but the post width should remain the same as original size.

Comment: Make panes more narrow. And if a distance is not an integer – just round it to the nearest integer.

Comment: I need the fence to be L meters long (where L could be a float number). Wouldn’t rounding it to the nearest integer make that impossible?

Comment: Great, thank you! I still need to figure out a way to adapt this solution to be using an existing 3D model, but this will help me out a lot in getting started.

Comment: I added a GitHub link with `Measure Tool` project.